# CSS Media queries works in Chrome but not firefox or safari

Tags: html, css, firefox, media-queries

I'm new on stackoverflow and would appreciate and help/input on this matter.

I have been working on a site and it works fine on chrome and is responsive to different device sizes. I tested it on numerous devices. However, on firefox it looks good on my 27"mac which i designed it too, but smaller screen devices it's not working. It's like it's not detecting the media queries at all.

Here is a link to the site: www.ujimatrading.com

and here is a paste of the media query css: http://pastebin.com/uQgzxeTQ

Sorry but i'm a backend developer and not really into front-end stuff so any tips would be highly appreciated.

Many Thanks

Comment: Some HTML would be nice.

Comment: I thought you can use browser view source to get that?

Comment: You're asking a question, and we're here to help. Don't give us a hard time - make it easy for us to help you. =)

Comment: alright, sorry was being rude :) will this help? https://jsfiddle.net/jmc1u42s/

Answer (score 0):

You've got some bad nesting going on.

Try cleaning it up like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width://pixels) { 

}
@media screen and (max-width://pixels) {

}
```

Comment: no luck with that i checked the braces with sublime text and they match up, also added the meta tag and no luck either :(

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the Viewport hasn't been set.
Try adding this to your html code:
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Explaination [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp)